I am getting "No active UnityEngine.XR.XRInputSubsystem is available." and 2 other samilar error and a black screen when i start my AR Unity project
Getting errors these 3 error:

No active UnityEngine.XR.XRInputSubsystem is available. Please ensure that a valid loader configuration exists in the XR project settings.
UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.ARInputManager:OnEnable () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@5.1.4/Runtime/ARFoundation/ARInputManager.cs:24)
2)No active UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRSessionSubsystem is available. This feature is either not supported on the current platform, or you may need to enable a provider in Project Settings > XR Plug-in Management.
UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.ARSession:OnEnable () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@5.1.4/Runtime/ARFoundation/ARSession.cs:342)
3)No active UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRCameraSubsystem is available. This feature is either not supported on the current platform, or you may need to enable a provider in Project Settings > XR Plug-in Management.
UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation.SubsystemLifecycleManager`3<UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRCameraSubsystem, UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRCameraSubsystemDescriptor, UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRCameraSubsystem/Provider>:OnEnable () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@5.1.4/Runtime/ARFoundation/SubsystemLifecycleManager.cs:67).

Along with that I get a black screen everytime I start the game have done everything I can to solve it on my own. Help.
I have tried updating plug ins and all but i feel like the problem is in Google AR Core.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
